# How to predefine a method call from a jar file?

Tags: java, android, jar, android-gradle-plugin

It's kind of a logical problem
For this question I'll try to be as clear as possible.

Suppose I have an activity 'A' and a jar file which will be called from 'A'.
'A' also have a method that sends your name for example, to the jar file. And the jar file has a method called init(). 
Now when init() is called from A, the jar should somehow be able to call the method in 'A' that sends the data to jar .

This is the problem statement in broader terms.
Please ask to clarify if not well explained

Thanks.

Comment: Can you change the code inside the jar?

Comment: No. It is a jar that is provided by 3rd party

Comment: This jar has some form of callback system? If it hasn't, you cannot do it

Comment: I am not sure about this. But I guess it doesn't have one.

Comment: As long as you don't have access to the jar source code and you are not able to modify it, you need to provide more info about what the jar can do, the methods available, etc. As Antonio has mentioned, If the jar is a third party lib, the only way to call 'A' is through a callback method, or an interface provided by the jar itself that you can implement on any of your classes and pass the object to the jar to be called later, but all depends on the jar implementation really